# Compare outcomes of two functions

Tags: javascript, protractor

A little bit of a newbie to protracor but what I am trying to acheive basically is a check (from another function) perform an action then perform the same check (from same function as earlier).

I have tried the below but unforunately get     `Failed: first is not defined`

```
checkCanvasWidth: {
    value: function () {
        return element(by.css("div[class='canvasWrapper'] > canvas")).getAttribute("width").then(function(width) {
            return width;
        });
    }
},


zoomIn: {
    value: function () {
        this.checkCanvasWidth().then(function (width) {
            var first = width;
            console.log("before:" + width);
        });

        //performs a click
        this.clickZoomIn();

        this.checkCanvasWidth().then(function (width) {
            var second = width;
            console.log("after:" + width);
        });

        expect(first).toBeGreaterThan(second);
    }
}
```

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define first and second outside the this.checkCanvasWidth() . Functions create scope, so only the function you use with checkCanvasWidth has access to first and second respectively. You have to define them in the scope above those functions, so that the expect function can also see these variables.

```
zoomIn: {
    value: function () {
        var first,
            second;
        this.checkCanvasWidth().then(function (width) {
            first = width;
            console.log("before:" + width);
        });

        //performs a click
        this.clickZoomIn();

        this.checkCanvasWidth().then(function (width) {
            second = width;
            console.log("after:" + width);
        });

        expect(first).toBeGreaterThan(second);
    }
}
```

PS: if `checkCanvasWidth()` returns a promise, you'll have to rewrite this whole function, since you want to do the `expect()` call AFTER first and second ahve been set.

Promise version:

```
zoomIn: {
    value: function () {
        var first,
            second;
        this.checkCanvasWidth().then(function (width) {
            first = width;
            console.log("before:" + width);
            if (first && second) {
                expect(first).toBeGreaterThan(second);
            }
        });

        //performs a click
        this.clickZoomIn();

        this.checkCanvasWidth().then(function (width) {
            second = width;
            if (first && second) {
                expect(first).toBeGreaterThan(second);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shilly, I did require the promise version! This is what I was struggling with but wasnt aware

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the variable `first` and `second` available to the function.
Javascript has **function scope**, So the way you have defined `first` and `second` they are not accessible outside the function.

So, when you write code like below then variable second is only accessible to the anonymous function.

```
this.checkCanvasWidth().then(function (width) {
            var second = width;
            console.log("after:" + width);
        });
```

So you can declare the variable `first` and `second` outside, so that they are accessible and then set the values inside the then handler to set the values.

```
zoomIn: {
    value: function () {
        var first ;
        var second ;
        this.checkCanvasWidth().then(function (width) {
            first = width
            console.log("before:" + width);
        });

        //performs a click
        this.clickZoomIn();

        this.checkCanvasWidth().then(function (width) {
           second = width
            console.log("after:" + width);
        });

        expect(first).toBeGreaterThan(second);
    }
}
```